# Axios request inside Telegrams inline_query and onText

Tags: node.js, axios, instagram, node-telegram-bot-api

I have code which makes just one request and returns some data I want. Here it is:

```
let res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://www.instagram.com/p/${videoId}/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link?&__a=1&__d=1`,
        headers: {
            'Cookie': cookie,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
        }
    }).catch(e => console.log(e))

    return {
        url: res?.data.items[0].video_versions[0].url,
        cover: res?.data.items[0].image_versions2.candidates[0].url
    }
```

videoId variable is just what comes after /reels/*videoId* (sample: Ct8xziAqLKs).
What it does is just returns a direct url to video from Instagram Reels. And when this code executes inside the onText function from node-telegram-bot-api it works just as expected. However, I also have bot.on('inline_query') realization, and when executed through inline query, the axios give me the following error with the exact same request saying that "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401":

```
data: {
      message: 'Please wait a few minutes before you try again.',
      require_login: true,
      status: 'fail'
    }
```

I assume that inline_query runs somewhere behind a few times, and this may cause the problem. But each time I run the code above I have a console log which also runs just one time from onText as well as inline_query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just forgot to add cookie from env inside inline_query. Problem resolved.